# How to fix Qtcore4.dll can't find procedure entry point?

Tags: python, qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix QGIS error “Entry Point could not be located”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

I am working with QGIS, python2.5 and pyqt4 for py2.5.
My system variables are as follows:

```
path:=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Python25;C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis;

pythonpath:=C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python;
```

But when i try to run a .py file through the command shell it gives me this error:

```
python.exe-entry point not found. 
The procedure entry point: ??0QDataStream@@QAE@PAVQByteArray@@H@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

Qtcore4.dll is present in Qgis folder, why does the error occur? and it is not present in system 32 so what do i do then? it was present then i deleted it it still says that.

Comment: From your description of the problem, it doesn't seem like python can't find Qrcore4.dll, it seems like there is a problem with that file

Comment: okk thanx...so wat can be the solution?? Reinstalling...

Comment: Is the file in \bin or apps\qgis\bin? See the 3rd answer in the linked question. Furthermore, try updating to the current QGIS 2.0.1. The problem may be solved with that. Or reinstall in a folder without blanks in pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling most likely won't help. You seem to have **another version of QtCore4.dll** on your system. QGIS installation cannot overwrite it and Windows cannot be told to use the version supplied by QGIS. You have to delete/rename the other dll.

Where are the other QtCore4.dll files located? In System32 folder by any chance?

As Giovanni said: Rename qtcore4.dll in system32 into something else and QGIS will start.

Comment: yes..qtcore4.dll is present in system32 folder...

Comment: then you have to blame the software that placed qtcore4.dll into system32 instead of keeping it into its installation folder. Rename qtcore4.dll in system32 into something else and QGIS will start.