# libmysql.dll-procedure entry point error

Tags: python, qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix QGIS error “Entry Point could not be located”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

I am working with qgis,pyqt4 and python2.5.
I was getting error qtcore4.dll could not be located.so i set PATH variable as  C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4 so i get rid off it.
But now m getting the error:
  procedure entry error point free_defaults could not be located in the dynamic link library  LIBMYSQL.dll.
what path to set? is it of mysql?

Comment: Same problem and solution as described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/how-to-fix-qtcore4-dll-cant-find-procedure-entry-point

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use OSGeo4W installer that takes care of setting the right working environment without additional env.variables manipulations? It also uses newer Python now (2.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Well to use this function you will need one of these **libmysqld.dll** or **libmysqli.dll** in you c:\windows\system32 folder. Both of these files contain this function:
http://www.opendll.com/index.php?search=free_defaults

I hop that helped,
David