# I cannot start up QGIS and get an error message

Tags: qgis, dynamic

When I start up my QGIS, the following appears on the screen and it closes down. Please help me; I really need my files that are there and do my work as well.  The message says:

```
The ordinal 284 could not be located in the dynamic link library SSLEAY32.dll.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never had that error myself, but a quick Google search yielded many results.

According to many pages I viewed, this is caused by an incompatibility with the currently installed OpenSSL DLLs.

You need to download nad install the latest version of Win32 OpenSSL.

http://www.openssl.org/

http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Have a look at [this similar post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26676/7424).

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Do you mind accepting the answer so that other people know that this answer worked for you?  Thanks.