# Why can I not start Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix QGIS error “Entry Point could not be located”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

Why can I not start Quantum GIS?  What do I do about this following error message?

"The procedure entry point TIFFMergeFieldInfo could not be located in the dynamic link librarylibtiff.dll".

Comment: what os you're using? 
What steps you took to install qgis?
Which version of qgis?