# How to fix The procedure entry point squlites3_open_v2 could not be located in the dynamic link library squlite3.dll?

Tags: qgis, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix QGIS error “Entry Point could not be located”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

I downloaded QGIS to my laptop (Window 7 64b) yesterday but when I click on the desktop logo I get the following warning (!) massage: " The procedure entry point squlites3_open_v2 could not be located in the  dynamic link library squlite3.dll"

I already uninstalled the program once and reinstalled it but the problem persists

Comment: check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standalone installer, I would try to use the [OSGeo4W installer](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#12-OSGeo4W-Installer).

This installer will track and manage many of the packages, including sqlite, that you would otherwise have to install and maintain on your own.  It also gives you the option of easily adding support for other database types, for example, the [ESRI FileGDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26301/1849).

If the above installer doesn't work, try to give some additional detail about the problem, as some of the developers of [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) check these forums and may be able to help as well.