# QGIS 2.6 installation error

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

### [image]

I used to have QGIS 2.2 and 2.4. I've completely removed 2.4 and installed 2.6 by OSgeo4W (Advanced installation). Everything, like GRASS, tora, udig is working fine except QGIS. Moreover if i open 2.2, the plugins are not working. Might be due to python compatibility i guess.

I've tried the steps mentioned here [How to fix QGIS error "Entry Point could not be located"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-fix-qgis-error-entry-point-could-not-be-located). But didn't work out.

Edit:

I've completely uninstalled OSgeo4W and again followed the same - Advanced install - option. This time the error was ippj-5.3.dll missing. Again i've uninstalled every OSgeo4W component and also thoroughly removed registry traces.

Now, i've installed using Express install option and it was installed successfully & QGIS is running properly.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit Operating System?

Comment: @Mapperz 32 bit/Windows 7

Comment: Search your whole disk for libxml2.dll. There might be a wrong version in your windows path.

Comment: @AndreJ Even before reading your comment, i've uninstalled and removed the whole thing. I've edited the question. Pls have a look

Comment: Hard to tell from the distance.